# Calling unmanaged C++ via Java

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I needed a Java application to call unmanaged C++. I copied MSVCR90.dll manually from Visual Studio 2008 redist path to the vmware's Windows Server Datacenter.

This is the error I get:

> A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
>
> ```
>   EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x73b4ae7a, pid=1108, tid=2272
>
>  JRE version: 6.0_38-b05
>  Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (20.13-b02 mixed mode, sharing windows-x86 )
>  Problematic frame:
>  C  [MSVCR90.dll+0x3ae7a]
>
>  An error report file with more information is saved as:
>  ...\hs_err_pid1108.log
>
>  If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
>  http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
>  The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
>  See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
> ```

This is the C++ code:

```
 #include "stdafx.h"

 #include <stdio.h>

 #include "CCCheckString.h"

 #include <vector>

 #include <String>

 using namespace std;
 #include "jobHandler.h"

JNIEXPORT jbolean JNICALL Java_CCCheckString_Login
  (JNIEnv *env, jobject object, jstring host, jstring UserName, jstring Domain, jstring Password)
{
    bool result;

    jobHandler *handler = new jobHandler(); 

     const char *hostStr = (env)->GetStringUTFChars(host, NULL);
     string hostS(hostStr);
     const char *UserNameStr = (env)->GetStringUTFChars(UserName, NULL);
     string UserNameS(UserNameStr);
     const char *DomainStr = (env)->GetStringUTFChars(Domain, NULL);
     string DomainS(DomainStr);
     const char *PasswordStr = (env)->GetStringUTFChars(Password, NULL);
     string PasswordS(PasswordStr); 

         //if comment this line everthing is okey 
     **result = handler->Login(hostS,UserNameS,DomainS,PasswordS);**

    (env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(host, NULL);
    (env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(UserName, NULL);
    (env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(Domain, NULL);
    (env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(Password, NULL);


    delete handler;

    return result;

}
```

Below is the processing code in Java:

```
CCCheckString ccCheckString = new CCCheckString();

 result=ccCheckString.Login("xxx", "xxx", "xx", "xxx");
```

How can i fix the error?

Comment: add 4 spaces before any piece of code . Look at `My Processing code is below.(c++)`

Comment: So what is your `handler->Login` function doing? If it is working without it, the problem is most probably in there.

Comment: Definitely work with C#, maybe pointer problem? :(

Comment: Should I give more information ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I solved**.

Problem is that Login() accepts std::string but we cannot send it

We reorganize our Login() and it must take const char []

Ex:

```
bool ClassName::Login(std::string host,std::string userName,std::string userDomain,std::string userPassword)
{ //Orginal Code Here ....}

bool ClassName::Login(const char host[],const char userName[],const char userDomain[],const char userPassword[])
{
std::string strHost(host);
std::string strUserName(userName);
std::string strUserDomain(userDomain);
std::string strUserPassword(userPassword);
return Login(strHost,strUserName,strUserDomain,strUserPassword);

}
```

Everything is fine.